# How to add value(s) to an object from Terraform jsondecode without copying values over to another variable?

Tags: terraform

I have a following example of Terraform resources where I fetch values from secrets manager and pass them to the Lambda function. The question is how can I add extra values to an object before passing it to environment variable without replicating the values?

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "example" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.id
  secret_string = <<EOF
   {
    "FOO": "bar"
   }
EOF
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "example" {
  secret_id  = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.id
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example]
}

locals {
  original_secrets = jsondecode(
    data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example.secret_string
  )
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = local.original_secrets
  }
}
```

As a pseudo code I'd like to do something like this:

```
local.original_secrets["LOG_LEVEL"] = "debug"
```

The current approach I have is just to replicate the original values and add a new but of course this is not DRY.

```
locals {
    ...
    updated_secrets = {
        FOO     = try(local.original_secrets.FOO, "")
        DEBUG   = "false"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Terraform [merge](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) function to produce new combined map of environment variables.

```
lambda_environment_variables = merge(local.lambda_secrets, local.environment_variables)
```